# Which PayPal API should I use to send payments to affiliates

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I work for a website-company that pays a commission to partners who send traffic to our website. Currently we track the traffic referred to our site from the affiliates and then go through a tedious manual process of sending payment via PayPal.

This is the gist of our current process:

```
1. Review affiliate commission report (our website back end generates this)
2. Copy/paste email & amount fields, one at a time, into the PayPal Send Payment screen (open in a different browser tab)
3. Specify additional fields in the PayPay Send Payment screen and select "continue"
```

This can get very time consuming considering the number of affiliates we pay every month, so if possible we would like to automate this with a php script. I'm unfamiliar with any of PayPal's APIs - could someone please refer me to the API best suited for solving this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PayPal has 2 APIs for this kind of use cases.

1. [MassPay](https://www.x.com/community/ppx/mass_pay)
2. [Business Payments](https://www.x.com/community/ppx/businesspayments) through [Adaptive Payments](https://www.x.com/community/ppx/adaptive_payments) APIs

MassPay API is for sending payments in the back end (disbursements) to large number of recipients (250 through API or upto 3000 through [file upload](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_batch-payment-format-outside))

Adaptive Payments API can be used to send payments not only in the back-end but also allows you to payout your affiliates during the original transaction itself through chained payments. It also provides you a way to delay the affiliate payout until up to 9 0 days to handle things like product returns, etc. You can find information about how the delayed chain payments work [here](https://www.x.com/people/Praveen/blog/2010/06/27/i-can-has-delayed-chained-payments).

You can find php code samples for Adaptive Payments APIs [here on x.com](https://www.x.com/community/ppx/code_samples).