# Which Paypal API Should i use to pay our employee's?

Tags: php, api, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

We are building a system in our intranet to easy and quickly pay to our external employees for their monthly services, the quantities to be paid change every couple of weeks.

[According to this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820789/which-paypal-api-should-i-use-to-send-payments-to-affiliates) we have mainly two options to pay to our employees

- Mass Payments : We can't use it because we dont get the minimum required amount of money yet
- Adaptive Payments

So we choosed the second one, We took the [adaptivepayments-sdk-php](https://packagist.org/packages/paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-php) and decided to use the simplest way to perform a payment from our own account to a person having a basic paypal account by email,
here's the code to do that:

```
 #Create Request
 $receiver = new Receiver();
 $receiver->email = 'the.employee.email@example.com';
 $receiver->amount = '10';
 $receiver->paymentType = 'SERVICE';

 $receiverList = new ReceiverList($receiver);
 $cancelUrl='...';
 $returnUrl='...';
 $payRequest = new PayRequest(new RequestEnvelope("en_US"),'PAY', $cancelUrl,'USD',$receiverList,$returnUrl);
 $payRequest->feesPayer = 'SENDER';

 #Send Request
 $service = new AdaptivePaymentsService();
 $response = $service->Pay($payRequest);
```

Would this be the correct approach for our needs? or is there a much simpler solution for this?

To use Adaptive payments you need to request an APP ID to paypal on its [www.x.com](http://www.x.com) website, the problem is that they ask for TEST URL/USER/PASS and we just can't give away permissions to get into our intranet per our company policy, also i'm not sure if our 'application' is within their guidelines

Any help would be much appreciated, i feel a bit lost here,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mass Payments would be the easiest route to go. There isn't a minimum money requirement and only the following need to be met:

- Be in good standing for 90 days or more
- Be verified
- Ensure all PayPal limits are removed (This can be checked by logging into your PayPal account and going to https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_show-limits&req_from=view_limits)
- The account owner has to contact PayPal

***Note: The criteria may be changed in the future.

If you meet all of the criteria above give a call to PayPal support at 866-837-1851 and request Mass Payments be enabled. Even if you send one payment, Mass Payments will be able to facilitate it.

If Mass Payments is not an option then yes Adaptive Payments is the route to go. You'll want to apply for implicit payments so a payment will be sent with each API call. This is a more complicated route but once implemented it can be be used in a very efficient manner.

As far as the testing environment, PayPal will need to see the application to ensure it's in compliance with their rules and regulations. If it's possible I'd recommend having an external site with a simple interface on how you plan on using the API. PayPal having access the the intranet is not a requirement.

Comment: Actually we already tried to contact them over the phone but PayPal is not willing to give us MassPayments Api access because we don't reach certain billing threshold, so.. i'll go ahead with creating a demo site to get approved with adaptative payments,thx

Comment: If Adaptive Payments doesn't work out let me know by contacting me via my Profile details and we can try working out the Mass Payments issue.

Comment: Finally the application have been approved with AdaptivePayments, and we are able now to easily process the implicit payments, but still if MassPayments are an option the switch would be definitely worth, as the commissions look lower

Comment: We can give it a try! Feel free to contact me via my profile contact information and we can set up a time to go over the account and enabling mass payments.

Comment: @PP_MTS_Matt Same issue for me. Seems that PayPal heavily promotes Mass Pay (every google search I do on sending money returns to this), but then doesn't let customers use it. Will drop you a PM in case you can help.